# Output parts of a heredoc conditionally

Tags: arrays, bash

I've made a script that would ask the user for input and then evaluate the input from that file. I was wondering if I could do if else statements inside the cat string.

```
InfoCreateFile() {
    touch $InfoFile
    cat > "${InfoFile}" <<- 'EOF'
########################################
#          System Information          #
########################################

System IP=""
Domain=""
if [ "${panelinstall}" == "1" ]; then
    Panel Subdomain=""
fi
if [ "${nodeinstall}" == "1" ]; then
    Node Subdomain=""
fi
EOF
}
```

I know this is possible with arrays but I would like to do it without, arrays are a bit of a pain. Anyways, if there's no other solution.. could anyone give me an example of how I would do that using arrays?

Comment: A _quoted_ heredoc you can't put any logic in at all (unless it's logic processed by something other than the shell itself -- a template engine processing the file after the shell is done, or such); that what you get out is exactly byte-for-byte what you put in is the whole point of using one instead of a regular/unquoted heredoc.

Comment: Anyhow -- can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? A concrete example of what desired behavior would be would make this easier to speak to.

Comment: So could I use any logic there if I unquote the heredoc? Could you please give me an example as well?

Comment: Script creates the file using all of those variables in it and then the scripts checks them using grep and sed. For example, if the user doesn't want to install the node then remove that line entirely from the file.

Comment: The thing you pass to `cat` is ultimately just a string. If we can guess at all what you want, the `if` statements would go outside the `cat`, and maybe append to the file you created from `cat`. (As such, a command substitution like $([ "${panelinstall}" == "1" ] && echo 'Panel Subdomain=""')`would work inside the here document.)

Comment: So If I understand correctly I cat the first lines until it gets to the panel install if statement and then use echo to add it. Then it can continue with the rest of the file?

Comment: Without the question being edited to make it more clear what you're trying to do, I think _everyone_ is guessing at the other party's meaning/intent right now. That's pretty... categorically not ideal.

Comment: BTW, `System IP=""` isn't a valid assignment. Is there a command you're trying to call named `System` where `IP=` is a valid argument to that command? Or is the code you're generating intended to be run with a non-bash interpreter?

Comment: (And as an aside, there's no point to using `touch` to create a file before redirecting to it; the redirection itself will create the file if it didn't already exist)

Comment: Alright, thanks. System IP is just a non-bash interpreter, correct. Alright, I'll remove touch then.

Comment: I partially agree with “A quoted heredoc you can't put any logic in at all (unless it's logic processed by something other than the shell itself -- a template engine processing the file after the shell is done, or such);” We should beware `$(foo)` or  \`bar\` inside the strings…

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd just avoid `cat` here altogether; it's not giving you any value.

```
exec 3>"$InfoFile"                 # create and open output file
emit() { printf '%s\n' "$@" >&3; } # write each argument as a line in that file

emit '########################################'
emit '#          System Information          #'
emit '########################################'
emit ''
emit 'System IP=""'
emit 'Domain=""'
if [ "$panelinstall" = 1 ]; then
  emit 'Panel Subdomain=""'
elif [ "$nodeinstall" = 1 ]; then
  emit 'Node Subdomain=""'
fi
exec 3>&-                          # close output file
```

...is a lot simpler (and also more efficient to run) than something that *forces* use of a heredoc even when it's not called for, like:

```
cat >"$InfoFile" <<EOF
########################################
#          System Information          #
########################################

System IP=""
Domain=""
$(if [ "$panelinstall" = 1 ]; then
    echo 'Panel Subdomain=""'
  elif [ "$nodeinstall" = 1 ]; then
    echo 'Node Subdomain=""'
  fi)
EOF
```

Note how we use just `<<EOF`, not `<<'EOF'`; leaving out the quotes lets you do parameter expansions, command substitutions, &c inside the heredoc.

Comment: A grouping can also make this even simpler.